# I am having trouble pasting a serialized string into .txt and un-serializing it to retrieve the original value

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this since I have never serialized before. I am able to turn strings into byte[]s and then serialize them to a new string but am unable to save that serialized string to a text file, re-import it and convert it back to get the original value. Keep in mind this is a learning project. This is what I am doing so far

```
private string SerializeToString(string obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        byte[] Array = ms.ToArray();
//This is where I create the txt file and write to it
            File.OpenWrite(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)     + "\\Text.txt")
            .Write(Array, 0, Array.Length);



        ms.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Array);
    }

        private void txtCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
//I uploaded the file to drop box and can successfully download it but can not figure out
//how to get the original value out of it..
        string Url = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62170850/Text.txt";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        //webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        //webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        byte[] myDataBuffer = webClient.DownloadData(new Uri(Url));
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(myDataBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to deserialize it? and why are you converting to Base64?

Comment: So, your `DownloadData` is the base64 data post-serialization.  So you work backwards: `Convert.FromBase64String`, and then deserialize with `BinaryFormatter` back to your original object...

Comment: In my button click event. I am a bit confused. I didnt notice I was using ToBase as opposed to FromBase.Let me give it another shot

Comment: Garis I am trying to deserialize to get the original value. I want to be able to do this with complex classes.

Comment: I guess the issue I am having is my understanding of all the conversions. I start with a string > byte[] > base64string > .txt file the reverse would obviously be .txt > base64string > byte[] > string although when I download the txt file from drop box it is downloaded as a byte[]. Is the data that is contained inside that byte[] the same as the data that I would get if I memorystreamed the physical .txt on my hdd to a byte[]?

Comment: but you never converted the text that is saved to the file as Base64, you write the file then convert your string. Maybe you should convert before you save the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [webClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) and don't forget to convert downloaded string back to byte array with `FromBase64String` call before deserialization.